Performant way to get a list of Nodes along with the latest related node?
I have the following relationship:
(Thread)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(Message)
A Thread can have anywhere from dozens to thousands of Messages.
Here is my query to find a list of Threads, and also return the latest Message from each one if exists.
MATCH (t:Thread)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(m:Message)
WITH t, m
ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC
WITH t, COLLECT(m)[0] AS latestMessage
RETURN t, latestMessage

I'm struggling to understand if there's a way to rewrite this to avoid COLLECT(m)[0] and somehow use just the latest message?

The following query is more memory-efficient. It uses a CALL subquery to find the latest message for one thread at a time. This is unlike your query, which has to gather in memory all the messages for every thread.
MATCH (t:Thread)
CALL {
  WITH t
  MATCH (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(m:Message)
  RETURN m
  ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC
  LIMIT 1
}
RETURN t, m AS latestMessage


Consider avoiding sorting and using list comprehensions to optimize memory usage
MATCH (t:Thread)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(m:Message)
WITH t, collect(m) as ms, MAX(m.createAt) as lt
RETURN t, [m in ms where m.createAt = lt][0] as latestMessage

If you want to avoid "collect" entirely, you'll need to make a duplicate query, and I don't have enough test data yet to determine if this is a better option
MATCH (t:Thread)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(m:Message)
WITH t, MAX(m.createAt) as lt
MATCH (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(latestMessage:Message {createAt: lt})
RETURN t, latestMessage

If conditions permit, you can add a new relationship [NEW_MESSAGE]. When creating a new (t)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(m:Message), delete the old (t)-[:NEW_MESSAGE]->(: Message), and then create a new (t)-[:NEW_MESSAGE]->(m), so that you only need to query (t)-[:NEW_MESSAGE]->(m:Message)
